# Inconsistent datatype error on description field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to run the following code to query my database and to convert some of the rows into columns.

The code largely works, but for some reason I am getting the following error:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Here is my code:

```
select * from (

select 

j.project_key
,j.issue_type
,j.assignee
,j.reporter
,j."SUMMARY"
,j.priority
,j.status
,j.date_created
,to_char(next_day(j.date_created,'sunday'),'iw') as "Created Week"
,to_char(j.date_created, 'MON' ) as "Created Month"
,to_char(j.date_created, 'YYYY' ) as "Created Year"
,j.date_updated
,to_char(next_day(j.date_updated,'sunday'),'iw') as "Updated Week"
,to_char(j.date_updated, 'MON' ) as "Updated Month"
,to_char(j.date_updated, 'YYYY' ) as "Updated Year"
,j.date_resolved
,to_char(next_day(j.date_resolved,'sunday'),'iw') as "Resolved Week"
,to_char(j.date_resolved, 'MON' ) as "Resolved Month"
,to_char(j.date_resolved, 'YYYY' ) as "Resolved Year"
,j.due_date
,j.timespent
,j.description
,custom.CUSTOMVALUE 
,custom.CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME

from JIRA02.FCI4JIRA_COMMON_VIEW j

INNER JOIN JIRA02.FCI4JIRA_CUSTOMFIELD_VIEW custom ON j.project_key = custom.PKEY
)

pivot 
(
   MAX (CUSTOMVALUE)
   for (CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME) in ('Team','Fix/Resolution','Apps','Action Item','Tag','Saves:Tickets/week','Saves:Hours/week','Saves:Requests/week','Saves Justification')
)
```

I have managed to isolate the issue, to this line of code

```
,j.description
```

If I don't include this line at all, the code runs fine.

I have tried to convert the field, but that cause me another issue.

```
,to_char(j.description)
```

ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 7939, maximum: 4000)
22835. 00000 -  "Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: %s, maximum: %s)"

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dbms_lob.substr( clob_column, for_how_many_bytes, from_which_byte )
```

so instead of ***,j.description*** try below

```
,dbms_lob.substr( description, 100, 1 )
```

Credit: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:367980988799